# Div not Showing on extra small devices (xs) bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some divs that change if the user access from a desktop, a tablet or a mobile, and i have some issues with the div mobile i am using right now, i used this code to show if the resolution is the smallest one

```
<div class="col-md-9 contenidox hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
```

But it's not showing anything when i resize the browser to a small size (like mobile devices)

Here is my bootply code

http://www.bootply.com/LG64Xhg8GG

Comment: pretty sure it inherently uses the hidden-sm so just set the col of the xs such as col-xs-12

Comment: Thank you that was the issue

Comment: That is great!  Please accept my answer below so others can view it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It inherently uses the hidden-sm so just set the col of the xs such as col-xs-12

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that other div was inheriting the classes css, closed the div tag and worked

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `hidden-sm class` and replace it with `col-sm-12`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visible-xs` class. below the example is...

```
<div class="col-md-9 contenidox visible-xs">
```

now it is visible on mobile only.